# HTTP 404 Not Found Error in Spring 3.2.8 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application based in the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework 
I have this controller

```
@Controller
public class ApplicantApplicationsListController extends ApplicantController {


    /**
     * @throws Exception    
     *                                 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = {       "/medrano/applicant/home",                                   
                                    "/medrano/applicant/home/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String viewProductApplications   (@ModelAttribute("applicationApplicationsListForm") final ApplicationApplicationsListForm applicationApplicationsListForm,
                                             HttpServletRequest request,
                                             Model model ) throws Exception {

        return "applicantApplicationsView";

    }
```

But I got a `404` in the browser when I put

> http://127.0.0.1:7001/cage/medrano/applicant/home

Comment: why are you request `/cage` when your controller isn't mapped on it ?

Comment: cage is the application context

Comment: Please add the configuration, log and the location of the applicantApplicationsView

Comment: Just a sidenote: you know that this version of Spring is hopelessly outdated ?

Comment: yes, we have to migrate the project soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to Configure the Spring DispatcherServlet in the file web.xml with:

```
    ...             
    <servlet-mapping>
         <url-pattern>//medrano/applicant/home</url-pattern>  
         <url-pattern>//medrano/applicant/home/</url-pattern>           
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a mapping problem with your request mapping:

The annotation [**@RequestMapping**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) `value` property expects an array of `String`s, in your case:

```
value = {"/medrano/applicant/home",                                   
             "/medrano/applicant/home/",}
```

Is not a valid `String[]`, you have an additional `,` at the end, just remove it.

You can check the [**Spring MVC @RequestMapping Annotation Example with Controller, Methods, Headers, Params, @RequestParam, @PathVariable** tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example) for further exmaples on how to use it.

**Edit:**

- There's no need to use the brackets with a single value for both
     `value` and `method` properties.
- And why would you use the same value `"/medrano/applicant/home"`
  twice in your RequestMapping.

It could simply be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/medrano/applicant/home", 
                 method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: it has not fix the problem :-(

Comment: Try the suggestions in my edit, and please add your whole calss configuration.